# Streamlit application too slow after each user selection

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, streamlit

I am new to streamlit. I am creating a webservice through reading a spreadsheet (~2 million rows).
I created two drop down selection using columns "PRODUCTID", "PRODUCTNDC" from the table. However when a user is selecting the identifier from the drop down, it is reading a dataframe again and that makes it very slow. How can I improve the speed of this service?

Below is the code:

```
#import libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import openpyxl
import streamlit as st
from streamlit_extras.app_logo import add_logo

#page settings
st.set_page_config(page_title = 'FDA-NDC Code Service', layout="wide")
st.header('FDA-NDC Code Service')
#st.subheader('beta version')

#data reading & pre-processing
df = pd.read_excel(io='package.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', sheet_name= 'package')

#removing leading spaces and more than 1 space in column names
df = df[["PRODUCTID", "PRODUCTNDC", "NDCPACKAGECODE", "PACKAGEDESCRIPTION",  "STARTMARKETINGDATE", "ENDMARKETINGDATE", "NDC_EXCLUDE_FLAG", "SAMPLE_PACKAGE"]]
df['PRODUCTID'] = df['PRODUCTID'].str.strip()

product_list = list(df['PRODUCTID'].unique())

df6 = df.copy()

options_pid = df6['PRODUCTID'].unique().tolist()
selected_pid = st.sidebar.multiselect('Search product id',options_pid)

options_nid = df6['PRODUCTNDC'].unique().tolist()
selected_nid = st.sidebar.multiselect('Search product ndc',options_nid)


if selected_pid:
    df6 = df6[df6["PRODUCTID"].isin(selected_pid)]
    
elif selected_nid:
    df6 = df6[df6["PRODUCTNDC"].isin(selected_nid)]
    
else:
    st.markdown(
              f'<p class="header_title"> {str(df6.shape[0])} </p>',
              unsafe_allow_html=True,
          )

if selected_pid or selected_nid:
    st.dataframe(df6.reset_index(drop = True))
else:
    st.dataframe(df)
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Caching](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/advanced-features/caching) to avoid to reload your dataframe every time your page is reloaded.

From documentation:

> `st.cache_data` is the recommended way to cache computations that return data: loading a DataFrame from CSV, transforming a NumPy array, querying an API, or any other function that returns a serializable data object (str, int, float, DataFrame, array, list, …)

```
@st.cache_data
def load_excel_sheet():
    return pd.read_excel(io='package.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', sheet_name='package')

df = load_excel_sheet()
```

**Note**: if you prefer to load your file everytime but increase the speed, you should convert your excel file as parquet file with [`pyarrow`](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/index.html) and [`df.to_parquet`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_parquet.html).

I prefer the solution with `parquet` because underthehood `streamlit` uses `pickle` to serialize objects. It's a good idea to be generic but for a dataframe, you can use a better format. With `parquet`, you can filter your dataframe and load in memory only a subset of your dataframe, which is a great improvement!

Comment: @rshar. Is my answer clear?